# Processing an XML file with public doctype

Tags: xslt, doctype

I'm trying to process an SVG file with XSLT. I am having behaviors I don't understand, that involves the doctype declaration.

Here are two tests I've done. The first one gives me the expected result and the second gives me a result I don't understand. (tested with saxon and xalan).

#### Stylesheet used for the two tests :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()" >
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="svg">
        <xsl:text>svg</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Test n°1

source file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="768" height="430">

</svg>
```

result :

```
/svg
```

#### Test n°2

source file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20001102//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-SVG-20001102/DTD/svg-20001102.dtd">
<svg width="768" height="430">

</svg>
```

result :

```
/
```

Why does the doctype declaration modifies the behavior of the processing ?

Comment: Excellent Question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The SVG elements are in the SVG namespace**.

The DTD defines this, so:

```
<xsl:template match="svg">
```

is matching an element with the name of `svg`, but in no namespace. All the elements in the XML document are in the SVG namespace and this template doesn't match any node.

This explains the output.

**Solution**: Replace the template matching `svg` with one that matches `svg` in the SVG namespace, as in the following transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 >
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()" >
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates  />
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="s:svg">
        <xsl:text >svg</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates  />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20001102//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-SVG-20001102/DTD/svg-20001102.dtd">
<svg width="768" height="430" >

</svg>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
/svg
```

**Update**:

Several people asked me "How a DTD can set a (default) namespace?"

Here is an answer: XML and DTDs with it were made a W3C Recommendation before namespaces made it. In pre-namespace XML a namespace declaration is simply an attribute.

**DTD's can specify "default attributes"** -- attributes, which may be ommitted from an instance but will be automatically added with a default value.

So, one way to define a default namespace in a DTD is to define an `xmlns` default attribute for the top element of the document.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that DTD was not aware of namespaces at all. And I certainly did'nt expect that a DTD could set a namespace !

Comment: @barjak: I updated my answer with explanation how a DTD can define a namespace for the document it defines.